# Accepted Answered Questions percent dropping by 1 percent every couple days

Tags: support, accept-rate

On my name card or whatever you wanna call it where it displays my name under the questions or answers I have done. There is a number 0-100% I try endlessly to keep it at 100%, and when I notice it dipping, I go through my questions and look to see if maybe someone answered one recently that I didnt accept yet, or whatever the case may be.

However last couple days I have been going through my questions looking for the notices above them saying I didn't accept an answer on a given question. Yet none of them show that notice, I have even tried visiting as many as I can take in a sitting just to see if one of them does not have an answer checked. And yet again all the answers with exception of a couple new questions asked as of late all have checks.

Is there something I did wrong somewhere? Or is this a glitch in the preverbal matrix?
This I only notice on stackoverflow.com (with the PHP's and HTML's and the CSS's and stuffff)

Comment: What @animuson said. However, ***a 100% accept rate is not required;*** it may not even be desirable, if some of your questions never got adequately answered.

Comment: I don't typically pick answers just to pick them unless they actually helped. I do however try to answer some of my own questions over time when all else fails, and I have found the answers to my questions through other means up to and including a lot of trial and error, just for the sake of someone else finding them one day. The ones with no answers or unfufilling answers I tend to let be otherwise. All in all though, if not selecting an answer for the purpose of having a 100% accept rate when and where I can, I still like to know for my own curiosity which ones are the ones

Answer (score 3):

All four of your most recent questions have answers and are eligible to be counted towards the accept rate. If you hover over your accept rate, you'll see this:

> this user has accepted an answer for 254 of 258 eligible questions

I can't find the exact time period, but that notice above your questions in your profile list doesn't appear for some time after the question actually becomes eligible towards your accept rate.